# Connection pooling issues with Spring RedisTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I have a Spring boot app which talks to two different Redis clusters (on Amazon Elasticache). I'm using spring-data-redis 1.6.4. This is my code for the different Redis configurations:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public JedisConnectionFactory clusterAJedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(clusterAUrl);
    jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(clusterAPort);
    jedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
    return jedisConnectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public JedisConnectionFactory clusterBJedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(clusterBUrl);
    jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(clusterBPort);
    jedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
    return jedisConnectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean(name="clusterARedisTemplate")
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> clusterARedisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();

    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(clusterAJedisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );

    return redisTemplate;
  }

  @Bean(name="clusterBRedisTemplate")
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> clusterBRedisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();

    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(clusterBJedisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );

    return redisTemplate;
  }
}
```

And then, in my code I have something like this for using it:

```
@Service
RedisService {

  private final RedisConfig redisConfig;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Autowired
    public RedisCache(RedisConfig redisConfig, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.redisConfig = redisConfig;
        this.mapper = mapper;
  }

  @Async
    public void saveValueInClusterA(String cacheKey, MyObject myObject) {
            try {
        String cacheValue = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
                redisConfig.clusterARedisTemplate().opsForValue().set(cacheKey, cacheValue, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                LOGGER.error(...);
            }
    }

    public MyObject getValueFromClusterA(String cacheKey) {
        MyObject myObject = null;
        try {
            String cachedEntry = redisConfig.clusterARedisTemplate().opsForValue().get(cacheKey).toString();
            myObject = mapper.readValue(cachedEntry, MyObject.class);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            LOGGER.error (...);
        }
        return myObject;
    }

  @Async
    public void saveValueInClusterB(String cacheKey, MyObject myObject) {
            try {
        String cacheValue = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
                redisConfig.clusterBRedisTemplate().opsForValue().set(cacheKey, cacheValue, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                LOGGER.error(...);
            }
    }

    public MyObject getValueFromClusterB(String cacheKey) {
        MyObject myObject = null;
        try {
            String cachedEntry = redisConfig.clusterBRedisTemplate().opsForValue().get(cacheKey).toString();
            myObject = mapper.readValue(cachedEntry, MyObject.class);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            LOGGER.error (...);
        }
        return myObject;
    }

}
```

This works fine under normal load. However, when I did a load test and took a thread dump, I saw that most of the threads are waiting on something like this:

```
"XNIO-2 task-973" #1547 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f472c41d800 nid=0x2d4e waiting on condition [0x00007f4680851000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000004ab53fb58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:583)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:442)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:48)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:99)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:12)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.set(DefaultValueOperations.java:182)
    at com.mypkg.services.RedisService.saveValueInClusterA(RedisService.java:97)
    at com.mypkg.services.RedisService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa4c9d31.invoke( )
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651)
    at com.mypkg.services.RedisService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a879b180.saveValueInClusterA( )
    at com.mypkg.services.impl.MyImpl.method2(MyImpl.java:745)
    at com.mypkg.services.impl.MyImpl.method1(MyImpl.java:419)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor487.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
          …..
          …..
          …..
          …..
          …..
          …..
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000004b41253a0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

I set the max pool size as 128, even though AWS console says there are only 35 connections max at any time to the redis cluster. What is going on here? Is my redis configuration wrong? Or do I need to release the connections after every use? I thought Redis template handles all those internally. Is the fact that I'm connecting to multiple redis clusters causing some issue?

Thanks.

Comment: hey drunkenfist , i stumpled upon similar issue with latency problems that i suspected redis is the issue , and i was kind of lost to find the root cause. your approach to use thread dump in this context helpes me find the root cause ! thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The underlying connection pool is a blocking pool that blocks if the pool is exhausted. This can easily happen if you have sufficient concurrent requests and your pool size is less than the number of concurrent requests.

Increase the pool size to address the issue.

On a side note: You might want to upgrade your Spring Data Redis version as 1.6.4 is outdated since quite a while. Also, switching to the Lettuce driver does not require pooling. Your code shows operations that do not include blocking/transactional Redis commands so you should be fine with two connections in total (one to your first Elasticache, and the second one to your second Elascticache).

Comment: I tried setting the max pool size as 128. I still get the error, even though the AWS console says I have only a max of 35 connections at any time.

Comment: Any idea how I can create a Lettuce RedisConnection for having keys as String, and values as byte[]? I have asked this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292145/create-lettuce-statefulredisconnection-for-storing-string-as-keys-and-byte-array